# execute command on one host with all inventory hosts in parameter

Tags: ansible

is it possible to execute a command on on host with all inventory hosts in parameter ?

For exemple :
inventory file :

```
host1
host2
host3
```

I want to execute this command from the host1 only :

```
ssh toto@host1:"touch /tmp/test"
ssh toto@host2:"touch /tmp/test"
ssh toto@host3:"touch /tmp/test"
```

for this i use this code but it's not working. The code is executed only on one host

```
name: Execute test
  command: ssh toto@{{ inventory_hostname }}:"touch /tmp/test"
  delegate_to: host1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - name: execute test
      command: ssh toto@{item} touch /tmp/test
      loop: "{{ groups.all }}"
```

This will iterate over `groups.all`, which contains the name of every host in your inventory.